# Can I connect CJMCU-4541 MICS-4514 Carbon Monoxide Nitrogen Oxygen Sensor with Raspberry Pi zero

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi-desktop

This sensor **CJMCU MICS-4514 Carbon Monoxide Nitrogen Oxygen Sensor** is arduino compatible can it be used with raspberry pi

Comment: Yes, no problem.  But Rpi needs to use an ADC module (eg. MCP3008) to measure the analog signal of the sensor output (Arduino has ADC pins therefore doesn't need that).  (1) CJMCU-4541 MICS-4514 CO/NO2/H2/NH3/CH4 sensor Module - US$ 17
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32867246863.html.

(2) AliExpress CJMCU-4541 carbon monoxide nitrogen oxygen sensor - US$30
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32816725607.html

(2) MiCS-4514 Combined CO and NO2 Sensor Datasheet - E2v Tech.
http://files.manylabs.org/datasheets/MICS-4514.pdf